# Why is the arithmetic mean of arithmetic sum same as arithmetic mean of the first and the last term of arithmetic sum?

Tags: arithmetic, means

This is used in measuring the average velocity of uniform acceleration. I tried to figure it out myself but i couldn't do it.

Comment: What do you mean with the statement/question in your title. Please give an example.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You will be able to get more answers if you show that there was some effort form you to solve the problem.

Comment: @Typhon I´m not sure if the problem is clear since the mean of velocities is **not** calculated by the **arithmetic mean**.

Comment: @Typhon In general, the context is  not meaningless. In many cases an OP mean something different as it seems at the first look. I still need clarification, like at least 5 other users. And I suspect  that the OP really know what he/she want.

Comment: @Typhon The real life argument has nothing to do with the requirement of posting an anwer based on full context and information . It´s the other way round.

Comment: @Typhon Actually this was not for my homework. I just browsed through my next year physics course in school and noticed they had used this information. I'm only 16 so i couldn't figure it out myself. I was just interested on it.

Comment: @Typhon Ok. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this by a direct calculation
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a + i b)
=
\frac{1}{n} \left( n a + b \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i \right)
=
\frac{1}{n} \left( n a + b \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \right)
=
a + b \frac{n-1}{2}.$$

$$
\frac{1}{2} (a + a + b (n-1)) = a + b \frac{n-1}{2}.
$$

---

But probably it is better to regroup à la Gauss
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a + i b) = \frac{1}{n} (a + a + b + a + 2 b + \dots + a + b(n-1))=\\
= \frac{1}{n} ((a + a + b (n-1)) + (a + b + a + b(n-2)) + (a + 2 b + a + b(n-3)) + \dots )=\\=
\frac{1}{n} \frac{n}{2} (2 a + b (n-1))
=
\frac{1}{2} (2 a + b (n-1))
=
a + b \frac{n-1}{2}.
$$
This is better, in particular because in the first version I have taken for granted the formula 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{n-1}{2},
$$
which is the particular case of the formula we are trying to prove for $a = 0$, $b = 1$.

Comment: @Typhon, just added an explanation in that direction!

Comment: I'm sorry because i didn't notice your comment. I somehow didn't get a notification on my gmail. Your comment was well explained and clear thank you.

Comment: @Togi, no ptroblem, and ***thank you***!